# Remove duplicate in merge sort of linked lists

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, nodes, mergesort

I have made a method that merge sorts two linked lists in descending order. I am now having difficulty in removing duplicates. I have seen some remove duplicate methods but I want to implement in within my `mergesort` method and not create a new method. What should I add in my `mergesort` method in order to remove the duplicates in the output? Thanks in advance!

**Expected Output**

```
Input1: 90 90 20 30 
Input2: 3 1 3 2 1 3
Output: 90 30 20 3 2 1
```

**My Output**

```
Input1: 90 90 20 30 
Input2: 3 1 3 2 1 3
Output: 90 90 30 20 3 3 3 2 1 1
```

This is my **method to merge sort** the two linked lists in descending order. Not sure if this is the part where the duplication is being handled but I have marked it anyway.

```
public SLLNode<T> mergesort(SLLNode<T> n1, SLLNode<T> n2) 
    {  
       SLLNode<T> merged = null; // pointer for merged list  
       SLLNode<T> current = null; // head of merged list  

       if (n1 == null)  
            return n2;  
       if (n2 == null)  
            return n1;  
        

       int cmp = 0;  
       while (n1 != null && n2 != null) 
       {  
            cmp = n2.compareTo(n1);  
            if (merged == null) {  
                 if (cmp < 0) {  
                      merged = n1;  
                      n1 = n1.next;  
                 } 
                 else if (cmp == 0)
                 {
                    // ****handles the duplicate****
                 }
                 else {  
                      merged = n2;  
                      n2 = n2.next;  
                 }  
                 current = merged; // points to head of merged list
            } 
            
            else {  
                 if (cmp < 0) {  
                      merged.next = n1;  
                      n1 = n1.next;  
                      merged = merged.next; 
                    }
                 else if (cmp == 0)
                 {
                    // ****handles the duplicate****
                 }
                  else {  
                      merged.next = n2;  
                      n2 = n2.next;  
                      merged = merged.next;  
                 }  
            }  
       }

       // append the remaining nodes of the either list  
       if (n1 == null)  
            merged.next = n2;  
       else  
            merged.next = n1;  

       return current;  
    }
```

**Main Method**

```
System.out.println("Output:");
SLL<Integer> mergedList = new SLL<>(); 
mergedList.head = mergedList.mergesort(list1.head, list2.head);  
mergedList.print(mergedList.head);
```

## Edit

**Updated mergesort**

```
    public SLLNode<T> mergesort(SLLNode<T> n1, SLLNode<T> n2) 
    {  
        SLLNode<T> merged = null; // pointer for merged list  
        SLLNode<T> current = null; // head of merged list  

        if (n1 == null)
            return n2; 
        
        if (n2 == null) 
            return n1;  

        int cmp = 0;  
        while (n1 != null && n2 != null) 
        {  
            cmp = n2.compareTo(n1);  
            if (merged == null) 
            {  
                if (cmp < 0) 
                {  
                    merged = n1;  
                    n1 = n1.next;  
                } 
                else 
                {  
                    merged = n2;  
                    n2 = n2.next;
                }  
                current = merged; // points to head of merged list
            } 
            
            else 
            {  
                if (cmp < 0) 
                {
                    if (merged.compareTo(n1) != 0) 
                    {
                        merged.next = n1;
                        merged = merged.next;
                    }
                    n1 = n1.next;
                } 
                else if (cmp == 0) // handles the duplicate
                {
                    if (merged.compareTo(n1) != 0) 
                    {
                       merged = n1;
                       merged = merged.next;
                    }
                    n1 = n1.next;
                    n2 = n2.next;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    if (merged.compareTo(n2) != 0) 
                    {
                        merged.next = n2;
                        merged = merged.next;
                    }
                    n2 = n2.next;
                }
            }  
        }
        
       // append the remaining nodes of the either list  
       while (n2 != null) 
       {
            if (merged.compareTo(n2) != 0) 
            {
                merged.next = n2;
                merged = merged.next;
            }
            n2 = n2.next;
        }
        
        while (n1 != null) 
        {
            if (merged.compareTo(n1) != 0) 
            {
                merged.next = n1;
                merged = merged.next;
            }
            n1 = n1.next;
        }
        merged.next = null; 

        return current;
    }
```

**SLLNode Class**

```
public class SLLNode <T extends Comparable<T>> 
{
    public T info;
    public SLLNode<T> next;
    
    public SLLNode(T el) 
    {
        info = el;
        next = null;
    }
    
    public SLLNode(T el, SLLNode<T> ptr)
    {
        info = el;
        next = ptr;
    }
    
    public int compareTo(SLLNode<T> ptr) 
    {  
        return ((Comparable)info).compareTo(ptr.info);
    }  
    
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.info.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You use HashMap or HashSet to store the data it prevents duplications and is also faster than a list. Even you can convert it into list as well when you want with just single function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic will only work if the 2 input lists are already sorted. Assuming they are, to remove duplicates in your code you can compare `merged` and (n1 or n2) before updating `merged.next`. Also in the end rather than directly updating `merged.next = n1` you will have to traverse through n1 and compare merged with n1. You can also used `equals` instead of `merged.compareTo(n1)`.
The below code can be used in the else block of `merged==null`. `else if (cmp == 0)` is not required when `merged == null` as it does not matter if n1 or n2 is set when they are equal.

```
if (cmp < 0) {
    if (merged.compareTo(n1) != 0) {
        merged.next = n1;
        merged = merged.next;
    }
    n1 = n1.next;
} else if (cmp == 0) {
    // ****handles the duplicate****
    if (merged.compareTo(n1) != 0) {
       merged.next = n1;
       merged = merged.next;
    }
    n1 = n1.next;
    n2 = n2.next;
} else {
    if (merged.compareTo(n2) != 0) {
        merged.next = n2;
        merged = merged.next;
    }
    n2 = n2.next;
}
```

The last part can be replaced with

```
while (n2 != null) {
    if (merged.compareTo(n2) != 0) {
        merged.next = n2;
        merged = merged.next;
    }
    n2 = n2.next;
}
while (n1 != null) {
    if (merged.compareTo(n1) != 0) {
        merged.next = n1;
        merged = merged.next;
    }
    n1 = n1.next;
}
merged.next = null;
```

Comment: Thanks! This resolved the duplicates but the program is now unable to print negative values, should I update a part of the code you have given?

Comment: What is the compareTo implementation you are using? I'm using `return ((Comparable) this.data).compareTo(o.data);`

Comment: I added an edit portion in my question to show my current `mergesort` method and my `SLLNode<T>` class with the current `compareTo` implementation.

Comment: This is strange I'm able to print negatives also, `list1 = 90, 90, 30, 20,-20,-20,-30,-100` and `list2 = 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1,-2,-2,-3,-3` `output = 90, 30, 20, 3, 2, 1, -1, -2, -3, -20, -30, -100` with print method `while (node != null) {
                System.out.print(node+", ");
                node = node.next;
            }`

Comment: I am able to accept negative inputs now however I am encountering this exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "SLLNode.compareTo(SLLNode)" because "<local4>" is null` for certain inputs like `list1 = 1 2 3 4`, `list2 = 0 1 2 3`. The exception is pointing to `if (merged.compareTo(n2) != 0)` in `while (n2 != null)`.

Comment: I've updated the code, in 1 place it was `merged = n1` instead of `merged.next = n1`

Comment: This update worked, thanks a lot!